# Upgrade to KDE Plasma 5.20 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: upgrade, kde

How do you upgrade from the default packaged KDE Plasma 5.19 on Ubuntu 20.10 to Plasma 5.20?

Comment: It'll require Qt5 5.15 (your system is 5.14.2 now) & a fair amount of your stack upgraded; meaning you'll end up with much of your system on *hirsute*. This could create issues come *release-upgrade* time.. Personally if you absolutely need it, I'd just move to the *development* cycle, but you'll be off-topic here as support options will reduce...

Comment: I blame all these net articles about how great 5.20 is :-)

I tried the Wayland option of KDE on 20.10 because I run a 4K monitor in a laptop+4K monitor multimonitor setup. It's almost functional but the Display Configuration has no 'Primary' checkbox so the primary (i.e. system tray) remains on my laptop - i.e. windows not opening where I want. With *gorilla* 20.10 just released, I think it's maybe too early to run *hirsuite* but thats probably the best option